# Unable to put JSON into InfluxDB

Tags: python, json, influxdb

I'm getting frustrated trying to put data inside an InfluxDB. How do I do this? I have data that looks like this:

```
fields = {'value': 1, 'value2': 2, 'value3': 3}
```

I want to add a date timestamp to it so I set it up like so:

```
json_body = [
    {
        "timestamp": "2018-10-30",
        "fields": fields
    }
]
```

Then I use

```
client.write_points(json_body, database='database')
```

This gives me an error `Unable to Parse : missing fields`. I've tried a lot of different things as well, for example:

```
json_body = {}
json_body["timestamp"] = "2018-10-30"
json_body["fields"] = fields
client.write_points(json_body, database='database') # returns 'str' has no obj attribute 'get'
client.write_points([json_body], database='database') # returns unable to parse : missing fields
```

Can somebody point out what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Please give a [mcve].

Comment: what, *exactly* is `fields`? Where are you getting it from? What does `print(type(fields))` give you, and `print(repr(fields))`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

JSON uses double quotes.  So you need to change your single quotes to double quotes in your fields dict.

fields = {'value': 1, 'value2': 2, 'value3': 3}

Change To

fields = {"value": 1, "value2": 2, "value3": 3}

And to do this you need to:

```
import json

#Your code to create json_body

client.write_points(json.dumps(json_body), database='database')
```

Comment: You are totally correct! Only, I have no idea how to convert fields from single quote to double quote. Tried json.dumps() and that just returns a literal string of the entire thing. Unfortunately fields is something I do not create, it is returned to me from another library

Comment: This answer makes no sense. Those two dictionaries are exactly equal in Python.

Comment: I should have clarified. I guess I am not looking for a dict. I am looking for a string? For example, here is my output when I try Jason's answer:

`[{'date': '2018-10-30', 'fields': '{"value1": value1, "value2": value2, "value3": value3}'}]`

I would like to see the output:
`[{"date": "2018-10-30", "fields": {"value1": value1, "value2": value2, "value3": value3}}]`

One is a complete JSON representation, the other is not

Comment: Sorry part of my post was omitted.